# Set max and min stringLength for Zend ValidatorRules

Tags: validation, zend-framework

I am in the beginning of learning Zend Framework.

I need to check if a string has exceed the maximum, say, 200, and minimum length is 0.

Here is the validatorRules I created:

```
$validators = array('descr' => array(array('stringLength', array('max'=>200))));
```

But this validator return false if the stringLength is 0.

What I want is a validator that make sure my string is below 200. (length of 0 is acceptable)

edit: I am not using form, instead, is a REST web service, that accept input from query string, so 'setRequired' is not working in my case.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok make sure you don't have `setRequired(true);` (or set it to false if you like) and then use `addValidator('stringLength', false, array(0, 200))`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I didn't state clearly what I want in my question. I want the validator to return true, even my string is length 0. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using Zend_Form, instead, I am using Zend_Rest_Controller, where the inputs are passed in from querystring.

Comment: Yes, I found it.
array('allowEmpty' => true, array('stringLength', false, array(0, 200)))
set allowEmpty to true.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. But I don't see any error message displayed when the text length is not between the limit of 2 and 200.

The is the code I used.

```
    $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
      'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
      'validators' => array(array('StringLength', false, array(2, 100)),),
      'required' => true,
      'label' => "First Name",
      'value' => "firstname",
      'class' => 'classname'
    ));
```

Comment: What mean param false, after 'StringLength',?

Comment: Sorry for the Late info. (The second parameter is used to indicate whether or not failure of this validator should prevent later validators from running; by default, this is FALSE.) https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.form.quickstart.html